# WPF Visibility Converter not Firing

Tags: wpf, converters, ivalueconverter

I can't seem to get my visibilty converter to work.  I think the issue is that i'm setting the relevant property in the constructor, so it's not picking it up down the line.  Code is below, any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

MainWindowViewModel:  (this is the main page; clicking a button will open a second window)

```
var newWindow = new SecondaryWindow
                {
                    Title = title,
                    DataContext = new SecondaryWindowViewModel{MyData = data, ShowAdditionalColumns = false}
                };
newWindow.Show();
```

Secondary Window:
Here's the relevant XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <myApp:DataGridVisibilityConverter x:Key="gridVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Print" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lines" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalLines}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowAdditionalColumns, Converter={StaticResource gridVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

And the Secondary ViewModel code:

```
private bool showAdditionalColumns;
public bool ShowAdditionalColumns
{
    get { return showAdditionalColumns; }
    set
    {
        showAdditionalColumns= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => ShowAdditionalColumns);
    }
}
```

Here's the converter; pretty standard stuff here.  I've put a breakpoint in the convert method; and it's never hit:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class DataGridVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var booleanValue = (bool)value;
        return booleanValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show code for the visibility converter.

Comment: Since the object isn't fully constructed when the property is set nothing can be listening for the property changed event. Some crazy ideas: Is there a reason that ShowAdditionalColumns can't be a Dependency property? I believe that would solve the problem. Or you could setup a handler for the SecondaryWindow's DataContextChanged event and set the property in the handler...

Comment: Does the output window complain anything? Other `DataGridTextColumn`s bind correctly?

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged(() => ShowAdditionalColumns);` What it does.. Show the `PropertyChanged` implementation..

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid`'s columns are not part of the visual/logical tree, so they don't get the `DataContext` inheritance. If you debug the program, you'll see the error in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or 
>   FrameworkContentElement for target element.

There are a few options here.

- Use this solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx
- Reference some control that does have an appropriate data context. It's easiest to use the root container (e.g. user control).

  First initialize a resource named "This" in code (must be called before `InitializeComponent`):

  ```
  public MyUserControl()
  {
      Resources["This"] = this;
      InitializeComponent();
  }
  ```

  Then reference it in XAML:

  ```
  <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource This},
                      Path=DataContext.ShowAdditionalColumns,
                      Converter={StaticResource gridVisibilityConverter}}" />
  ```

(As a side note, the binding you provide for the column's data works because it is copied to the row in the grid, where the data context is set by the `DataGrid` to the data item.)